# How to select an attribute based on another attribute's value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to select the `NativeDescription` value when `Credit_Term_Code="4"`  by looping in XSLT:

```
<Credit_code_parents>
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="1" NativeDescription="Letter of Credit" EnglishDescription="Letter of Credit" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="2" NativeDescription="Cash on Delivery" EnglishDescription="Cash on Delivery" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="3" NativeDescription="Contract" EnglishDescription="Contract" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="4" NativeDescription="Net" EnglishDescription="Net" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="5" NativeDescription="Contract" EnglishDescription="Contract" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="6" NativeDescription="Net" EnglishDescription="Net" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="7" NativeDescription="Contract" EnglishDescription="Contract" />
  <Credit_Term_parent Credit_Term_Code="8" NativeDescription="Net" EnglishDescription="Net" />
</Credit_code_parents>
```

Comment: While posting question, please post Input XML, tried XSLT or XPATH and required result.

Answer (score 3):

To select the `NativeDescription` attribute of the `Credit_Term_parent` element with a `Credit_Term_Code` equal to 4, **use one of the following XPaths**:

1. If the ancestral structure above `Credit_Term_parent` is fixed as shown:

   ```
   /Credit_code_parents/Credit_Term_parent[@Credit_Term_Code='4']/@NativeDescription
   ```
2. If there's potentially variable ancestral structure above
   `Credit_Term_parent` (and assuming that the provided `Credit_Term_Code` is unique across the document):

   ```
   //Credit_Term_parent[@Credit_Term_Code='4']/@NativeDescription
   ```

**You ask for XSLT looping code:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Credit_code_parents/Credit_Term_parent">
   <xsl:if test="@Credit_Term_Code=4">
     <xsl:value-of select="@Credit_Term_parent"/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Or, without the loop:**

```
 <xsl:value-of
          select="//Credit_Term_parent[@Credit_Term_Code='4']/@NativeDescription"/>
```

...or, alternatively, use the XPath from #1 above instead of the one from #2.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
<xsl:for-each select="Credit_code_parents/Credit_Term_parent">
  <xsl:variable name="temp" select="@Credit_Term_Code"/>
  <xsl:if test="$temp='1'">
    <check>
      <xsl:value-of select="@NativeDescription"/>
    </check>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope that helps.